# Change variables type in multiple data frames

Tags: r, loops

I have several data frames with different names and same date variable. I want to change the type of the variable to `yearmon`. I've tried to create list with all data frames and change the type, but I can't `unlist` the data as it was. Tried all codes in this site, but there's always some error. I think in my case I have to approach this with loop.

This is the code so far:

```
df=data.frame(date=c("201101","201102","201103"),value=c(3,4,6))
df2=data.frame(date=c("201101","201102","201103"),value=c(3,4,6))
df3=data.frame(date=c("201101","201102","201103"),value=c(3,4,6))

library(zoo)

# list of all impoted dataframes
files <- ls()[sapply(mget(ls(), .GlobalEnv), is.data.frame)] 

for (i in files){        #search for the dataframe name                                                       
  for (j in length(get(i)[,1])){   #get the length of current data frame
  d[j]=get(i)[j,1]     #gets current data frame’s Date_col (the column with date)
  d[j] <- as.yearmon(as.character(d[j,]), "%Y%m") #convert 
  assign(get(i)[j,1],d[j])  # an error shows here 
  }
}
```

This is the code that I tried for dataframes in list.

```
l.df <- lapply(ls(), function(x) if (class(get(x)) == "data.frame")
get(x))
files <- ls()[sapply(mget(ls(), .GlobalEnv), is.data.frame)]
names(l.df) <-  files

lapply(l.df, transform, date=as.yearmon(as.character(date, "%Y%m")))
```

It returns NA for date.

Answer (score 2):

We can do(**Note:** You need to set `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE` while forming your data sets or convert date to character before using this solution, see below):

```
lapply(my_list ,
       function(x) 
       transform(x, 
                 date=zoo::as.yearmon(anytime::anydate(x$date))))
```

**Result:**

```
[[1]]
      date value
1 Jan 2011     3
2 Feb 2011     4
3 Mar 2011     6

[[2]]
      date value
1 Jan 2011     3
2 Feb 2011     4
3 Mar 2011     6

[[3]]
      date value
1 Jan 2011     3
2 Feb 2011     4
3 Mar 2011     6
```

**Data:**

```
df=data.frame(date=c("201101","201102","201103"),value=c(3,4,6),
              stringsAsFactors = F)
df2=data.frame(date=c("201101","201102","201103"),value=c(3,4,6),
               stringsAsFactors = F)
df3=data.frame(date=c("201101","201102","201103"),value=c(3,4,6),
               stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: You can uses without anonymous function as well `lapply(my_list, transform, date = zoo::as.yearmon(anytime::anydate(date)))`

Comment: Thanks. I am still unfamiliar with how to use non anonymous functions with the apply family. Will take more time to learn that.

Comment: I just realised that for 201811 and 201812 the code returns Jan 2018 and Feb 2018, because it takes the rightmost symbol - 1 and 2, not 11 and 12.

Comment: My solution is
lapply(my_list,
               function(x) 
                 transform(x, 
                        Dates=zoo::as.yearmon(as.character(x$Dates),"%Y%m")))